# Multiple markers on google map

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to display multiple addresses on a map, but it shows just the first one which is retrieved from the database. This is the code:

```
 <?php if($places) { foreach 
    ($places->result_array() as $place) { ?>

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {



       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations("'<?php echo $place['number']?>','<?php echo $place['street']?>', '<?php echo $place['city']?>' ,'<?php echo $place['country']?>'", function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
             map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()));
          }
       });
    } <?php }}?>
```

How can I display multiple markers on the same map?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you create a new map instance on every iteration

you should move `var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));` outside of the loop (place it before) and it should work

Comment: by the way, why are you using such an old api? v3 is much simpler to use